# ul width is not the width i set

Tags: html, css, listitem

when setting this line:

```
<ul style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green">
    <li style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid blue"> 1 </li>
</ul>
```

I got a ul that  is a lot wider than my 100px setting.

Any ideas why it ignores my settings?
How to set **li** and **ul** with the same width (without the extra indentation )?

**update: people, you were too eager to vote me down  because of a spelling mistake (on the style attribute) ,that you forgot the main question here, which is the ul width issue**

ok, i solve it, just needed to add :

```
  <ul style="....;padding:0"> ... </ul>
```

thanks...

Comment: if you vote down, at least explain why?

Comment: Your CSS is very invalid. You should never use commas between properties - use semicolons instead. Also use background-color not backgroung-color. Also better to have a semicolon after the last CSS property, although not needed in newer browsers. If you ran it through a validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator you would have found these problems.

Comment: Oh and I didn't vote down BTW

Comment: you are absolutely right, and next time i will post my question more carefully, but my question remained the same...

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green;">
    <li style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid blue;">1 </li>
</ul>
```

replay your code with this. you are using , after width: 100px, it should be ; :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use ; everywhere you use , between width and height...

Answer (score 1):

yes ,  use of comma between width and height

Replace with :

> style="width:100px; height:100px;

Answer (score 1):

Hey now your **code is wrong**

now remove come  and

**replace** `backgroung-color`

**into**

```
background-color
```

now finel code is

```
<ul style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green;">
    <li style="width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid blue"> 1 </li>
</ul>
```

**[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/IYxEFnFb)**

Comment: thank for your answer,i had spelling mistakes in my question, but that still doesn't solve my problem